# Delete multiple rows in csv file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk, csv

I'm working on this assignment to delete rows from a CSV file with different customers. I've figured out how to delete one specific customer by using this code:

```sh
delete() {
  awk -F "\"*;\"*" '$1 != '$@' {print $ALL}' input.csv > output.csv
}

delete $@
```

However, now I have to delete multiple customers at the same time. I can identify a customer by their customer number which is stored in the first column of the csv file. I'm supposed to create an array for the different customer numbers and create a while loop to loop through the array, but I can't seem te figure it out.

Comment: What is `$ALL`? How is `print $ALL` different from `print`? And why are you passing `$@` in single quotes? That means it won't be expanded.

Comment: @terdon the single quotes appear to close before and then open again after `$@` (it's still not a good way to pass shell parameters to awk though)

Comment: @steeldriver ah, yes, thanks. Still, as you say...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are wrapping this in a shell function - I will assume that's a requirement of your assignment.

First, note that using `"*;"*` as a field separator in Awk is not a robust way to handle quoted CSV fields - it will fail for example if either the first field or last field on a line is quoted, and it won't preserve quoted delimiters (i. e. quoted fields that actually contain a `;`) which misses the whole point of quoting CSV fields.

Second, you should not try to pass shell variables (or positional parameters) into Awk expression that way - the correct way is either to export them and then access them via the `ENVIRON` array, or use command line option `-v`. So your "single customer" implementation would be better written

```sh
delcust() {
  awk -F '"*;"*' -v cust="$1" '$1 != cust' input.csv > output.csv
}
delcust "$1"
```

While you *could* modify this to pass multiple positional parameters, I'd suggest passing the customer list via standard input and parsing it as a file of values; that way you can do a canonical Awk lookup based on an associative array (or hash):

```sh
delcusts() {
  printf '%s\n' "$@" | awk -F'"*;"*' 'NR==FNR {custs[$0]=1; next} !($1 in custs)' - input.csv > output.csv
}
delcusts "$@"
```

Note that you don't need an explicit `print` in Awk since `print` is the default action if a rule evaluates non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a need for an array. You could define your function like this:

```sh
delete() {
  awk -v customer="^($1)\$" -F ";" '$1 !~ customer {print $ALL}' input.csv >output.csv 
}
```

I didn't understand how you defined the field separator, so I changed it to be able to test. The relevant part is to use a negated regular expression `!~`. Also I used the `-v` parameter for awk that can save you from a lot of shell quoting headache.

With this you can use a parameter like this to delete multiple customers:

```sh
delete 'bla|foo'
```

For in input.csv like this:

```sh
bla;blu;bli
foo;faa;fii
blafoo;blufaa;blifii
```

it would yield

```sh
blafoo;blufaa;blifii
```

in output.csv.

If you really want to use an array you could in addition define a little helper function that prepares the array for use with the `delete()` function above:

```sh
join() { local IFS=\|; echo "$*"; }
```

With this you are able to define a bash array and convert it to regex alternate syntax:

```sh
$ a=(bla blu)
$ join ${a[@]}
bla|blu
```

Then you could call `delete()` like this:

```sh
$ a=(customer1 customer2)
$ delete "$(join ${a[@]})"
```

(Small side note for zsh users: the `join()` function is not needed for zsh, you could simply use the following parameter expansion: `${(j:|:)a}` to join all array elements with the `|` character)